# how to enable and disable the context menu based on checkbox condition in dojo dijit?

Tags: dojo

```
function(Menu, MenuItem){
    var pMenu = null;
    pMenu = new Menu({
        targetNodeIds: ["progmenu"]
    });
    pMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Simple menu item",
        onClick: function(){
            pMenu.destroy();
        }
    }));
```

this create the context menu on the div, but i want to disable the context menu when the it is unchecked and again enbale it when it is checked.can some one help me..
my html page is..

```
<div id="progmenu" >
        <input type="checkbox" /> click </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dijit/Menu` itself has no way to be disabled, however, each `dijit/MenuItem` can be disabled by using the `disabled` property.

So, if you want to disable the menu, you loop over all the menu children using `dijit/Menu::getChildren()` and then you set the property.

To get the state of the checkbox, you use `dojo/on` or `dojo/query` to add an `onChange` event handler to it, and with `event.target.checked` you can check if it was checked or not.

For example:

```
query("#progmenu input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(evt) { // On change
    pMenu.getChildren().forEach(function(child) { // Loop over children
        child.set('disabled', evt.target.checked); // Set disabled state
    });
});
```

A demo can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/659t7dfj/

Small note, I'm using [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the menu items. If you need to support older browsers you have to switch to a regular loop or use the `dojo/_base/array` utility module.